# Как загрузить файл в вк через api

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Как будучи на своей странице в вк с помощью javascript загрузить файл(из url) в документы

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Документ получится загрузить только с сервера, либо с клиентского приложения. У сайтов таких прав нет.